# Complexity: Is it more efficient to store two objects as variables or as array [2]?

Tags: complexity-theory

Is it more efficient to store two objects than variables or as array [2], or doesn't it make any difference?

I am sorry if this is a dump question.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the language. For example in c/c++ it is the same, on the other hand in Java the array has some overhead and therefore more expensive.